# primefaces qr code not shown?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using primefaces to develop a web app.I am trying to show the bar code on mhe webpage.All coders are shown except the QR code.I have read that two jar files are required for this 
[image: sample]

- **barcode4j: 2.1**
- **qrgen: 1.4**

I have added these jar files in the lib folder & try running it.In this way i get 404 error when i add qrgen in lib folder.

I tried doing it using maven i added the depedency as follows:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.glxn</groupId>
    <artifactId>qrgen</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.barcode4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>barcode4j-light</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

but i get error for second dependency so i copied the barcode4j in lib folder but i can't print the QR code.please help me out.

**code for xhtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <title>login</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>

   <p:panelGrid columns="2">
    <h:outputText value="Interleaved 2 of 5" />
    <p:barcode value="0123456789" type="int2of5" />

    <h:outputText value="Codabar" />
    <p:barcode value="0123456789" type="codabar"/>

    <h:outputText value="Code39" />
    <p:barcode value="0123456789" type="code39" />

    <h:outputText value="Code128" />
    <p:barcode value="0123456789" type="code128"/>

    <h:outputText value="EAN-8" />
    <p:barcode value="20123451" type="ean8"/>

    <h:outputText value="EAN-13" />
    <p:barcode value="0123456789012" type="ean13"/>

    <h:outputText value="UPC-A (PNG)" />
    <p:barcode value="01234567895" type="upca" format="png"/>

    <h:outputText value="UPC-E (Vertical)" />
    <p:barcode value="01234133" type="upce" orientation="90"/>

    <h:outputText value="PDF417" />
    <p:barcode value="0123456789" type="pdf417"/>

    <h:outputText value="DataMatrix" />
    <p:barcode value="0123456789" type="datamatrix"/>

    <h:outputText value="Postnet" />
    <p:barcode value="0123456789" type="postnet"/>

    <h:outputText value="QR" />
    <p:barcode value="0123456789" type="qr"/>
</p:panelGrid>
    </h:body> 

</html>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.prime</groupId>
    <artifactId>primedemop</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>primefaces</name>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>5.1</version>
        </dependency>
          <dependency>
        <groupId>net.glxn</groupId>
        <artifactId>qrgen</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>


    </dependencies>![smaple][2]
</project>
```

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29993696/maven-depedency-not-working-in-primefaces/) specifically resolves the issue around Maven dependencies. What you need to do is 1) Prove that your source code compiles while using libraries from the QR code package and 2) Show us in your source code where you attempt to use these libraries. What we're seeing here doesn't appear to be a problem with the dependency management, but something else. Without the full picture, nobody can help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you're doing all ok.But you missed on one thing.The qrgen-1.4 you are using are further having dependencies as **zxing-core-2.0** & **zxing-javase** trying including these two jar files into your build path these might work well.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```xml
 <!-- Barcode: print QR -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.nayuki</groupId>
            <artifactId>qrcodegen</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>barcode4j-light</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: This depends on the PrimeFaces version you are using. The io.nayuki dependency was added later. It will not work with PF 5.1.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the [dependencies](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/13_0_0/#/gettingstarted/dependencies) page of the documentation. There you can find which dependencies are needed for the barcode and QR-code to work. Note though that these dependencies will **not be the same for each version for PrimeFaces**, so make sure to check if the version of the documentation is matching your PrimeFaces version. The link I've added here points to 13.