# Maven depedency not working in primefaces?

Tags: java, maven, jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces

I wanted to show the barcode in primefcaes.For that i created a maven based project & added two dependency for those libararies such as

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.glxn</groupId>
    <artifactId>qrgen</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.barcode4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>barcode4j-light</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I read in primefaces documentation that barcode4j-2.1 may not be available in maven so i need to `manual install the jar in maven repo`

I have installed the jar into maven repo using this command in eclipse

```
install:install-file -Dfile=D:\qrgen-1.4.jar -DgroupId=net.glxn -DartifactId=qrgen -Dversion=1.4 -Dpackaging=jar

 install:install-file -Dfile=D:\barcode4j-light-2.1.jar -DgroupId=net.sf.barcode4j -DartifactId=barcode4j-light -Dversion=2.1 -Dpackaging=jar
```

**POM.XML**

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.prime</groupId>
    <artifactId>primedemop</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>primefaces</name>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.glxn</groupId>
            <artifactId>qrgen</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.barcode4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>barcode4j-light</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

But i can't see any barcode generated if i was adding the barcode4j-light-2.1 jar file in **lib** folder then i was able to generate bar code but not the QR code but now i can't generate not even barcode.

I get the following output on eclipse console when i install the jar file into maven repo.

**For qrgen jar**

[image: pic1]
**for barcode4j** 
[image: pic2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the groupId and artifactId's for your dependencies and what you installed:

```
qrgen:       -DgroupId=net.glxn.qrgen -DartifactId=qrgen
qrgen-light: -DgroupId=net.glxn.qrgen -DartifactId=qrgen
```

Your dependencies show a different group/artifactId:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.glxn</groupId>                 <--- here
    <artifactId>qrgen</artifactId>              <--- here
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.barcode4j</groupId>         <--- here
    <artifactId>barcode4j-light</artifactId>    <--- here
    <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

You manually installed your jars to a directory in the maven repo called `net/glxn/qrgen/qrgen` but your dependencies are expecting to find them in `net/glxn/qrgen` and `net/sf/barcode4j/barcode4j-light` respectively.

You need to update your manual install commands to:

```
install:install-file -Dfile=D:\qrgen-1.4.jar -DgroupId=net.glxn -DartifactId=qrgen -Dversion=1.4 -Dpackaging=jar
```

and

```
install:install-file -Dfile=D:\barcode4j-light-2.1.jar -DgroupId=net.sf.barcode4j -DartifactId=barcode4j-light -Dversion=1.4 -Dpackaging=jar
```

Comment: I did the same as you suggested.Now i am able to generate the barcode but not able to get the qr code?@Ryan J

Comment: I did the same as you suggested.Now i am able to generate the barcode but not able to get the qr code?@Ryan J'

Comment: @AnkitSharma can you update your question with the commands you used and your POM file? Can you display somehow that the dependencies are being properly resolved, to eliminate some other non-Maven related issue?

Comment: @AnkitSharma looks like you still have an incorrect groupId for the qrcode lib. `-DgroupId=net.glxn.qrgen` should be `-DgroupId=net.glxn`

Comment: I am sorry i updated wrong code on stack overflow but in actual i am using the way as you suggested.Please now check the install command & dependency.I am still not able to print the qr code.Please help me out.i have been having hard time figuring it out. @Ryan J

Comment: Please tell me the way out?

Comment: @AnkitSharma Are you able to compile your code using imports for the `net.glxn.*` packages? if so, then Maven is working properly, it's something else in your code that's not working. Maven is a dependency manager, so if the functionality you're expecting isn't there, but the libraries are, then something else is wrong.

Comment: Yeah i added the dependency.I am able to generate the barcodes of like barcode,linecode,upc,data matrix & so on.But the only problem is with the QR codes.I am not able to generate it.I have tried so many ways.Please help me I have been sturggling for three days now. @Ryan J

Comment: @AnkitSharma The root of your question was about Maven dependencies. Sounds to me like the dependency issue is resolved, and you have some other problem with your implementation. My suggestion would be to mark this question resolved and open up a new question and post your source code and why you're not seeing what you expect.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29976277/primefaces-qr-code-not-shown/ here i have already asked this question but not getting any good solution.I was told to use maven for this.I used maven & i came with this issue which is kindda resolved but output is not getting @Ryan J

Comment: Can you provide me the solution? @Ryan J

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76805/discussion-between-ankit-sharma-and-ryan-j).